# Django 1.4 - django.db.models.FileField.save(filename, file, save=True) produces error with non-ascii filename

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm making a fileupload feature using django.db.models.FileField of Django 1.4

When I try to upload a file whose name includes non-ascii characters, it produces error below.

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 109-115: ordinal not
>   in range(128)

The actual code is like below

> file = models.FileField(_("file"),
>                           max_length=512,
>                           upload_to=os.path.join('uploaded', 'files', '%Y', '%m', '%d'))
>
> file.save(filename, file, save=True)  **#<- This line produces the error
>   above, if 'filename' includes non-ascii character**

If I try to use `unicode(filename, 'utf-8')` insteadof `filename`, it produces error below

> TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

How can I upload a file whose name has non-ascii characters?

Info of my environment:

> sys.getdefaultencoding() : 'ascii'
>
> sys.getfilesystemencoding() : 'UTF-8'
>
> using Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.encode()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode the string:

```
file.save(filename.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), file, save=True)
```

Comment: I tried that but it still produces the same error. I guess 'save()' may encode its first argument with 'ascii' again inside itself. I tried to find the source code of 'save()', it was so difficult for the novice like me.

Comment: Use the second argument, then. Have edited my answer.

Comment: 'ignore' doesn't work either.
'save()' invokes django's 'generate_filename()' and I suspect this method might be do the encode('ascii') again.

Comment: Then I am afraid the problem could be anywhere in your web stack. Check this post for some places to look http://itekblog.com/ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position/

Comment: Finally, I got an answer for that! Thank you @arocks Your link really helped me out. I still have a problem when an uploaded file is not utf-8 but iso-8859-1, for example. But I think I can handle it. I will arrange the tip and link here soon. Thank you again. ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your FileField definition the 'upload_to' argument might be like os.path.join(u'uploaded', 'files', '%Y', '%m', '%d')
(see the first u'uploaded' started with u') so all string will be of type unicode and this may help you.

Comment: That's right. But the solution was not in the python source, but in the apache environment variables.